# How to fetch data from database instead of JSON everytime

Tags: android, json, wordpress, android-recyclerview

Actually, I followed [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObU-wCqoo2I) and got an idea of delivering articles from a WordPress blog using the JSON API.

Here is the [GITHUB](https://github.com/filippella/Retrofit2-RestApiDemo) link.

The above tutorial has a good example, but it only shows data from database only when there is no internet connection available. But I want the following:

1. Fetch data when the app is first started.
2. Store the data in the database
3. Set the adapter and show the data in the recyclerview
4. When the app is loaded for the second time check if internet is available and then check for new data, download if available, and then save the data into database and show the data in the recycler view.

Now, I've developed most of the logic for it, but the tutorial has used some advanced OOPs principles of JAVA which I am unable to fully comprehend. 
Can anyone please help me and tell me how I can change the given code and display the data from database even if internet is available or not?

Answer (score 0):

on MainActivity, line 91

```
if (getNetworkAvailability()) {
        getFeed();
    } else {
        getFeedFromDatabase();
    }
```

Above code will check network, and if network available, getFeed() which load feed from internet will be called. Just remove that case. I mean, remove above code, just keep the line

```
getFeedFromDatabase();
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing complex, by the way. The idea is that you define your own interface which describe how to save data and implement it for database and for communication with Rest Api (Retrofit). There may be some differences between format of stored data (one form in database and the other on a server), so you have to convert it to format of your app.
For that you create another interface (see Repository pattern), which is also implemented by you db and web stuff. 
When your have implementations for both sources you can choose which one to use.